# Proper way of typesetting an angle in degrees with a power of ten

Tags: siunitx, typography

I have a very tiny angle: 5,3x10^(-5) degrees. What is the proper way to typeset it?

In:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\begin{document}
    $\SI{5.3e-5}{\degree}$\\
\end{document}
```

I don't know if the result is correct. To me it looks awful that the small circle of the degrees is so close to the exponent and I'm pretty sure who reads it would interpret it as 5,3x10^{-50}.

With `\ang{5,3e-5}` I can't get it to accept the power of ten and I can't find any mention of such a case in the `siunitx` manual or anywhere else.

Comment: I don't think you're asking for `\ang{0;0;.1908}` but I want to mention that the possibility exists.

Comment: Have you tried `\ang{5.3e-5}`, i.e. `.` instead of `,`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The possibility exists for sure, but I'm afraid my students wouldn't be able to check if whatever the calculator spits out is the same as `\ang{0;0;.1908}` (it's actually not that difficult, but go tell them...)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using words? `$\SI{5.3e-5}{}$ degrees` Little chance for misinterpretation that way.

Comment: @SandyG There's absolutely nothing wrong with that. There's always more than one way to skin a cat. Probably that is what I will end up doing. I was just wondering if there is any standard rule (like by the AMS) for this case, which I don't recall having ever seen in any book or paper.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a tiny space before the degree sign using the option `quantity-product` (or `number-angle-product` if you use `\ang`). Alternatively, you could use a variation for the scientific notation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker = {,}
}

\begin{document}
    $\SI[quantity-product = \,]{5.3e-5}{\degree}$
    
    $\SI[output-exponent-marker = \mathrm{e}]{5.3e-5}{\degree}$
\end{document}
```

[image]